# Bad Substitution in Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to use subtitution to kill process's for example:

`kill ${lsof -t -i:3000}`

and I get the following error:

`bash: ${lsof -t -i:3000}: bad substitution`

If I run `echo $0`, it is running bash.

How can I resolve this? I am pretty sure my substitution syntax is correct.

Comment: `lsof -t -i:3000 | xargs kill`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the *lsof* command inside **parentheses** (command subsitution) instead of braces in order to kill every processes (files) that uses the port 3000.

```
kill $( lsof -t -i:3000 )
```

Comment: I guess my substitution syntax was incorrect! thanks.